# Python: Adding attributes to mutables inside a function

Tags: python, mutability

I try to understand what best practices are in cases like this please. Suppose we have a dict (or a list or some other mutable) which is altered inside a function (but defined outside it)

```
d = {'a': 0}

def my_fun(x):
    for i, el in enumerate(x):
        d[el] = i + 1
```

Calling `my_fun(['b', 'c'])` and then `print(d)` will print `{'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}` which is fine. However the same can be done by adding a return statement to the function (although not necessary). Or even, the return statement plus a second arg in the function representing the dict:

```
d = {'a': 0}

def my_fun(x, d):
    for i, el in enumerate(x):
        d[el] = i + 1
    return d
```

Both the return statement and the second arg are redundant here, I just find they help in terms of clarity. It is easier to read. Calling `d = my_fun(['b', 'c'], d)` and then `print(d)` will print again `{'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}`

Finally, you could choose to pass a copy of the mutable object: `d = my_fun(['b', 'c'], d.copy())` which is probably more pythonic but I dont know for example if making copies is good practice in terms of memory management.

What is considered best practice here? How do you handle these types and add attributes to mutables inside functions?

Comment: Put the mutable & the methods that modify it into a class.

Comment: It is generally considered an antipattern to have functions mutate their inputs.

Comment: Although a dictionary is like a class in this case, hence making the contents of the dictionary mutable is understandable.

Comment: @Har even if it were an *instance of a custom class*, that doesn't make it good practice for a function to mutate it's arguments.

Comment: Agreed, mutating its arguments is bad practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good practice to modify a mutable like that in a function. You're right that both the methods you've suggested modify the original object. It's better to return a new object for a simple case like this.

In this simple example you could, as you say, copy the dict. IMO you should do this in the function. You need to be clear from the outset what the structure of the dict is, because you might need a deep copy.

```
def my_fun(x, d):
    d = d.copy()
    for i, el in enumerate(x):
        d[el] = i + 1
    return d
```

Or you could create a new dict and update it with the old one. I prefer this, but you'd have to be careful about repeat keys.

```
def my_func(x, d):
    result = {el: i for i, el in enumerate(x)}
    result.update(d)
    return result
```

For a more complicated thing, you might have a class to encapsulate the entire thing.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def update(self, x):
        for i, el in enumerate(x):
            self.d[el] = i
```

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. A class looks to be the cleanest way and it is also easier to refactor

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are not equivalent. They only appear that way because you happened to name the function parameter the same as a global. An equivalent function is:

```
d = {'a': 0}

def my_fun(x, foo):
    for i, el in enumerate(foo):
        foo[el] = i + 1
    return foo
```

But this function is not "pythonic". Its okay to modify an object being passed in, but when you do so, don't also return it. If you make a copy of the object in the function, then return it. All you did was create an ambiguity - at a glace I would assume from the return statement that the original dict was not modified. As for clarity, that's what doc strings are for. Now everyone who types `help(my_fun)` knows what's going on.

```
def my_fun(x, foo):
    """Update foo with an enumeration of x"""
    for i, el in enumerate(foo):
        foo[el] = i + 1
```

Your first example is the most risky. It does a silent update of a global object. We try to avoid that sort of thing. And when its done, the doc string and hopefully the name of the function itself make it clear that some hanky panky is going on.

As for copying, that's something that you could let the caller decide. Updating the dict passed into your function is a bit more generic than copying it because the caller could decide whether the data being updated should be copied or not. Of course, since you aren't returning the updated object anymore, there is a bit more work for the caller.

```
d_copy = d.copy()
my_fun(['b', 'c'], d_copy)
```

This isn't so bad. The code is clear. Its not like we are running out of newlines or something.